# How to access variables in @BeforeClass method in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm using Junit 4.12 to run unit tests.  I'm trying to setup test objects once for all my tests in my test class to use so I don't have to setup for every test.

However, when I try to access these variables from my tests, I'm getting an error.  Can anyone explain to me what I need to do to get everything working?

I don't want to post proprietary code so I tried to write a quick example of what I'm trying to do.  Please excuse any typos or logical errors:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class InventoryTest extends TestCase {
    private Inventory inv;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setupTestObjs() throws Exception {
        inv = new Inventory();

        Book b1 = new Book();
        CD c1 = new CD();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddNew() {
        inv.addNew(b1);
        inv.addNew(b1);
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is Eclipse is complaining that b1 cannot be resolved to a variable.  However, I have defined it in my setupTestObj method that should be run before any tests are ran.  What do I need to do to allow my tests to see the variables in the setupTestObj method to run tests on?

Answer (score 3):

Your `@BeforeClass` method needs to be static and so do the variables it accesses. Try the following code, `b1` should be accessible in `testAddNew()` now. Note that I have moved `b1` to class level.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class InventoryTest extends TestCase {
    private static Inventory inv;
    private static Book b1;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupTestObjs() throws Exception {
        inv = new Inventory();

        b1 = new Book();
        CD c1 = new CD();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddNew() {
        inv.addNew(b1);
        inv.addNew(b1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The scope of `b1` is limited to the `setupTestObjs()` method. Therefore it cannot be accessed in `testAddNew()`.

(You didn't post your compiler error, so I'm assuming the error occurs in `testAddNew()`.)

To make this work, ie. setup `b1` once for all your tests, you will need to give it class scope, ie. declare it straight after `inv`.

Your `setupTestObjs()` method and the test fixtures will need to be `static` for `@BeforeClass` to work as intended.

Comment: Thanks.  The error said "b1 cannot be resolved to a variable" in Eclipse.  There was a red "X" on the line so no compile error, just whatever Eclipse found before compiling.  I'll try it with the real code to see if that's my problem.

Comment: For some reason, it's not running the setupTestObjs method.  I put a System.out.println() in both setupTestObjs() and testAddNew() but it's only printing the line from testAddNew().  Is there another thing I overlooked?

Comment: I found out the reason.  It seems like I can't make the class extend TestCase.  That caused it to not run the setupTestObj method.  Thanks for your help.